# Can i fill Array a with A or B without using IF?

Tags: php

**EDIT:**

Found my solution :D

```
while( $something = fgets(...) ) 
{
$var[$counter++] = array( $tmp[0] => $something[10)],
                          $tmp[1] => str_pad($something[4],1,0) // 0 if empty
                          $tmp[2] => str_pad($something[7],1,0) // 0 if empty
                          $tmp[3] => str_pad($something[1],1,0), // 0 if empty
                          $tmp[4] => str_pad($something[12],1,"x") // x if empty
                         );
}
```

**Situation was this:**

I have following code...

```
// reading something from file....
$var; 
$tmp     = explode(",","aa,bb,cc,dd,ee");
$counter = 0;
while( $something = fgets(...) ) 
{
    $var[$counter++] = array( $tmp[0] => $something[10],
                              $tmp[1] => $something[4],
                              $tmp[2] => $something[7],
                              $tmp[3] => $something[1],
                              $tmp[4] => $something[12]
                             );
}
```

is there a way to let php choose what value is passed when other value is empty ?

e.g.

```
// reading something from file....
$var; 
$tmp     = explode(",","aa,bb,cc,dd,ee");
$counter = 0;
while( $something = fgets(...) ) 
{
    $var[$counter++] = array( $tmp[0] => $something[10],
                              $tmp[1] => $something[4]  || 0,
                              $tmp[2] => $something[7]  || 0,
                              $tmp[3] => $something[1]  || 0,
                              $tmp[4] => $something[12] || 0
                             );
}
```

it doesn't work like this :) saw some like this in javascript

or do i have to use **IF** all the time ? i don't want to use a short writen **IF** like

```
( $foo ? $foo : 0 )
```

eather. trying to avoid writing my var two times

output atm is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [aa] => 
            [bb] => "some"
            [cc] => 
            [cc] => "some"
            [ee] => 
        )
```

and i want this (ONLY on fields i've choosen):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [aa] =>         //<=== This can stay empty
            [bb] => "some"
            [cc] => 0
            [cc] => "some"
            [ee] => 0
        )
```

Comment: thx to all posters, i found my solution by my self :D

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to do it without having if statements all over the place, here's a way with only one if:

```
// reading something from file....
$var; 
$tmp     = explode(",","aa,bb,cc,dd,ee");
$counter = 0;
while( $something = fgets(...) ) 
    {
    //add in a while loop to find empty somethings:

    //----------------------------------
    $somethingCount = count($something);
    $at = 0;
    while($at < $somethingCount)
    {
        if(empty($something[$at]))
        {
            $something[$at] = 0;
        }
        $at++;
    }
    // ---------------------------------


    //now you can do your own thing without caring about the empties:

    $var[$counter++] = array( 
        $tmp[0] => $something[10],
        $tmp[1] => $something[4],
        $tmp[2] => $something[7],
        $tmp[3] => $something[1],
        $tmp[4] => $something[12]
    );
}
```

Still not quite at your no-if's goal of course.

.

[EDIT]

If the something[ ] array will only be numbers you could probably just do:

```
// reading something from file....
$var; 
$tmp     = explode(",","aa,bb,cc,dd,ee");
$counter = 0;
while( $something = fgets(...) ) 
    {


    $var[$counter++] = array( 
        $tmp[0] => max(0, $something[10]),
        $tmp[1] => max(0, $something[4]),
        $tmp[2] => max(0, $something[7]),
        $tmp[3] => max(0, $something[1]),
        $tmp[4] => max(0, $something[12])
    );
}
```

Comment: thank you for your post, no... there are numbers and strings and the while problem still has the problem that i dont want to have all statements set to zero if they empty. :) guess ill just write a function like **prepareEntry($string,$returnvalue=0)**

Comment: by writing you the comment and typing the function i had a idea and it works fine for my case :D see my edit on the top. thx anyway

Answer (score 0):

```
$tmp[4] => isset( $something[12] )? something[12] : 0
//         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^   ^
//                 condition           when true    else
```

Comment: this isn't what i was looking eather... it's a short form writing a if :) i don't want to have 1 var doubble :) its just a nicely thing

Comment: but it doesn't say "if"   ;)

Comment: true hahaha :) you don't even have to write isset it would still work